# How to tweet highlighted text?

Tags: twitter, autohotkey

So some of you have probably seen the script for searching highlighted text on Google
http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/13404-google-search-on-highlighted-text/

I am trying to figure out if it is even possible to highlight text, press a hot-key, and have it sent as a tweet. One of the problems I have come across is that there isn't a url to plop your tweet into and hit go like search queries and Google. Does anyone know if this would work, and how I should go about doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple example of how to do this:

```
function getSelectionText() {
var text = "";
if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
return text;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
$('div,p').mouseup(function (e) {
    if (getSelectionText() != "") {
        window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='+encodeURI(getSelectionText()) + '&url=' + encodeURI(document.URL));
    }
})
});
```

Basically, use Javascript to get any text in a p tag the user has selected, then open a new tweet window, taking the selected text as a paramater and also grab the current url.

Here's a JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/DanBrown180/c46GS/4/

Edit: And a slightly nicer version that gives you a button: http://jsfiddle.net/DanBrown180/pWt7L/2/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are plugins that can achieve this. There's a really nice JavaScript plugin that will do this for you called Tweetit.js

The plugin provides functionality so that users can highlight text on a page and the Twitter icon will appear allowing users to tweet the highlighted text.

The functionality it provides is almost identical to Medium.

Here's the description from the plugin website:

> Give your readers the ability to tweet anything in your blog or webpage. When some text is selected, the Tweet it button displays. Clicking on this button allows them to post the selected text in Twitter. You can add your webpage and hashtags to be pusblished with their tweets.

The plugin is lightweight and this functionality is it's sole purpose so it won't be overkill for your project.

[Here's a link to the plugin](http://marcossilva.info/tweetit.js/) page. It's very easy to set up and use!

Comment: Here is an alternative [link on Github.](https://github.com/sislandemarcos/Tweetit.js)

Answer (score 0):

There is a example on how to post to twitter in the autohotkey forums [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/16439-twitter/)

Your hotkey should send Ctrl c to copy the marked text to the clipboard and then send this as a status following the example linked. You need [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) to get this to work.

Mapping this to windows + t would look like this

```
#t::
Send, ^c
Clipwait

Run curl --basic --user USERNAME:PASSWORD --data status="%clipboard%" http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml,,Hide
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of feature is even more elegantly deployed here:

https://medium.com/spook-studio/25b830afbd84

It floats a button above the highlighted text.

Anyone know if they are using a plugin for this, or if they built it themselves?

Comment: Here's a not quite as nice JS Fiddle showing something similar I knocked up.
http://jsfiddle.net/DanBrown180/pWt7L/2/